# DoCmd.RunSQL Use Transaction equivalent in adodb.command

Tags: sql, t-sql, ms-access, adodb

In my MS ACCESS application i execute SQL code in 2 different ways.
First - DoCmd.RunSql
Second -  Adodb.Command + executing it after.

In first method i can set Use Transaction parameter to false. Is there any way to set Adodb.Command executing SQL code not to use tranactions? As i can do with DoCmd.RunSQL, by setting that parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADODB.Command doesn't use a transaction unless you explicitly start one in your code with yourConnection.BeginTrans. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680895%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

In short, the connection object controls the transactions, not the commmand object.